# I'm getting an Unhanded Rejection Error on JScript

Tags: javascript, async-await

This is a github script for a decentralized storage network but whenever I'm uploading, I get this Unhandled Rejection error in the await() function.

```
handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.file !== "") {
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        await this.state.files.add(this.state.file,this.state.file.name);
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        this.getALLHashes();
    }
    else {
        this.setState({ fieldReq: true })
    }
}
```

I'm new to JavaScript so I don't know how to resolve this.
Please help!!

Comment: what is `this.state.files.add()` ?

Comment: see this https://medium.com/@JonasJancarik/handling-those-unhandled-promise-rejections-when-using-javascript-async-await-and-ifee-5bac52a0b29f

Comment: "JScript" is dead... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript

Comment: @zynkn Hi I just posted the part where I got the error                                                                          this.setState({
                files : files,
                API_KEY : credentials.API_KEY,
                API_SECRET : credentials.API_SECRET

            });

Answer (score 0):

That means, if a error occure you dont have any mechanism that handles that rejection. Use a `try / catch`. Try it like this

```
handleSubmit = async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (this.state.file !== "") {
    try {
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      await this.state.files.add(this.state.file, this.state.file.name);
      this.setState({ loading: false });
      this.getALLHashes();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  } else {
    this.setState({ fieldReq: true });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the response. During the execution, I checked my logs and it turns out that during the POST I receive an error when I send a request.       request.send(requestData);

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being elaborate.